# Google Maps API v3: set a Marker based on the "postal code"?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know a Marker in Google Maps API v3 is created like this:

```
var myMarker=new google.maps.LatLng(45.776374,12.043793);
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myMarker,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
```

Corresponding to: https://maps.google.it/maps?q=45.776374,12.043793&ll=45.776486,12.045524&spn=0.008396,0.021136&num=1&t=v&z=16

Now let's suppose that I want to create the marker according to **Country and postal code**

Example: **31044,Italy** (which is more or less the same point marked by the code above)

Corresponding to: https://maps.google.it/maps?q=31044,Italy&hl=it&sll=45.776486,12.045524&sspn=0.008396,0.021136&t=v&hnear=31044&z=12

My goal is to creare a marker **without knowking the exact coordinates** but knowing **Country(Italy) and postal code (31044)** (let's think that a user joins to my web site and I want to fullfil a map with the location of the city of every user. Of course for every new user who joins a new marker is added).

How should I do it? I tried to look throughout API reference but I didn't find out a way. As far as I see the only way is to create a LatLng object accoridng to coordinates but I saw websites that only need the postal code.

Thank you in advance for any hint

Comment: Have you tried using the geocoding api  --> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ in Google Maps? Usually that is supposed to be able to convert an address to a corresponding lat / lng. It works better for some countries than for others so you may want to try that out. Also, i have never used it with JUST a zipcode so that will be something u will need to check

Comment: Finally I think I did it. Thank you for the helping :)